# Custom strongly typed html helper not returning model

Tags: c#, .net, model, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I'm having trouble with some custom Strongly Typed HTML Helpers which my team and I've created.
The Custom HTML helpers on which they are based work great, but when I try to use the Strongly Typed version of them, they accept and read the model using Lambda Expressions, but when I submit the form, they don't return the value.
I'm pretty sure that we've missed something when we develop them, because built-in strongly typed Html Helpers works great (I've done some test using the same model).

Here is the definition of one of my custom helpers:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, string idControl, string contenido, string alto = "", string ancho = "",
          Boolean activo = true, Boolean visible = true, string tooltip = "", Color cLetra = Color.Negro, EjeZ ejeZ = EjeZ.Normal) {
         TagBuilder label = new TagBuilder("label");
         label.MergeAttribute("for", idControl);
         //label.MergeAttribute("class", "Label");
         string estilos = string.Empty;
         if(alto.Length > 0) { estilos += "height:" + alto + ";"; }
         if(ancho.Length > 0) { estilos += "width:" + ancho + ";"; }
         if(!activo)
            label.MergeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
         if(!visible) {
            label.MergeAttribute("class", "Label Oculto");
         } else {
            label.MergeAttribute("class", "Label");
         }

         string letra = "none";

         switch(cLetra) {
            case Color.Rojo:
               estilos += "color:red;";
               break;
            case Color.Azul:
               estilos += "color:blue;";
               break;
            case Color.Verde:
               estilos += "color:green;";
               break;
            default:
               break;
         }
         label.MergeAttribute("Letra", letra);
         label.MergeAttribute("style", estilos);

         if(ejeZ == EjeZ.Frente) {
            estilos += "z-index:" + maxEjeZ + ";";
         } else if(ejeZ == EjeZ.Atras) {
            estilos += "z-index:" + minEjeZ + ";";
         }

         label.MergeAttribute("style", estilos);
         label.MergeAttribute("title", tooltip);

         label.InnerHtml = contenido;
         return MvcHtmlString.Create(label.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

      }
```

and my strongly typed helper, which calls the *normal* helper

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> label,
          string idControl, string alto = "", string ancho = "", Boolean activo = true, Boolean visible = true,
          string tooltip = "", Color cLetra = Color.Negro, EjeZ ejeZ = EjeZ.Normal) {
         var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(label);

         return Label(html, idControl, name, alto, ancho, activo, visible, tooltip, cLetra, ejeZ);
  }
```

This is my View (combos don't accept Lambda Expressions):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    @using GridMvc.Html;
    @model Consalud.ConsultaSalco.WebSite.Models.SuperModelo
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("VisorEventosModelo", "Test")) {
            using (@Html.Grupo("gruBusqueda", "Búsqueda")) {
                <div>@Html.Label("cmbTransaccion", "Transacción")  @Html.Combo("cmbTransaccion", Model.transaccion)</div>
                <div>@Html.Label("cmbEstadoTrans", "Estado Transacción")  @Html.Combo("cbmEstadoTrans", Model.estadoTransaccion)</div>
                <div>@Html.Label("numCodVenta", "Código Venta")  @Html.NumeroFor(m => m.codigoVenta, "numCodVenta")</div>
                <div>@Html.Label("rutBeneficiario", "Rut Beneficiario")  @Html.RutFor(m => m.rutBeneficiario, "rutBeneficiario", modo: Modo.Calculo)</div>
                <div>@Html.Label("cldInicio", "Inicio Vigencia") @Html.CalendarioFor(m => m.fechaInicioStr, "cldInicio")</div>
                <div>@Html.Label("cldTermino", "Término Vigencia")  @Html.CalendarioFor(m => m.fechaTerminoStr, "cldTermino")</div>

                <button type="submit" class="Boton" value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
            }

            using (@Html.Grupo("grpGrilla", "Resultados")) {
                @Html.Grid(Model.Eventos).AutoGenerateColumns().WithPaging(10).EmptyText("No hay datos para mostrar")
            }

        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Controller Code

```
  public ActionResult VisorEventosModelo() {
            SuperModelo modelo = new SuperModelo();
            //Cargo Dominios
            svcHomologacion svc = new svcHomologacion();    //instances a WCF Service
            Infrastructure.SvcHomo.Dominio[] svResultTransac = svc.ConsultaDominios("TRANSACCION", "0");    //gets the WCF service result
            Infrastructure.SvcHomo.Dominio[] svResultEstado = svc.ConsultaDominios("ESTADOS SERVICIOS", "0");    //gets the WCF service result
            List<Dominio> transac = new List<Dominio>();
            foreach (Infrastructure.SvcHomo.Dominio d in svResultTransac) {
                transac.Add(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Dominio>(d));
            }

            List<Dominio> estados = new List<Dominio>();
            foreach (Infrastructure.SvcHomo.Dominio d in svResultEstado) {
                estados.Add(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Dominio>(d));
            }

            foreach (Dominio d in transac) {
                SelectListItem itm = new SelectListItem();
                itm.Text = d.Codigo + " - " + d.Descripcion.ToUpper().Trim();
                itm.Value = d.Codigo;
                modelo.transaccion.Add(itm);
            }

            foreach (Dominio d in estados) {
                SelectListItem itm = new SelectListItem();
                itm.Text = d.Codigo + " - " + d.Descripcion.ToUpper().Trim();
                itm.Value = d.Codigo;
                modelo.estadoTransaccion.Add(itm);
            }

            modelo.fechaInicio = DateTime.Now.Date;
            modelo.fechaTermino = DateTime.Now.Date;

            return View(modelo);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult VisorEventosModelo(SuperModelo model) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {                     
                svcHomologacion svc = new svcHomologacion();
                Infrastructure.SvcHomo.Auditoria[] svAuditoria = svc.ConsultaAuditoria("0", "0", 0, model.rutBeneficiario, model.fechaInicio, model.fechaTermino);

                List<Auditoria> audit = new List<Auditoria>();
                foreach (Infrastructure.SvcHomo.Auditoria d in svAuditoria) {
                    audit.Add(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Auditoria>(d));
                }
                foreach (Auditoria a in audit) {
                    model.Eventos.Add(a);
                }
                return View(model);
            } else {
                return View();
            }

        }
```

And finally, the model I'm using:

```
public class SuperModelo {

    public SuperModelo() {
        transaccion = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
        estadoTransaccion = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
        Eventos = new List<Auditoria>();
    }

    public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> transaccion { get; set; }
    public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> estadoTransaccion { get; set; }
    public Decimal codigoVenta { get; set; }
    public Decimal rutBeneficiario { get; set; }
    public DateTime fechaInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime fechaTermino { get; set; }
    public List<Auditoria> Eventos { get; set; }

    public String fechaInicioStr {
        get { return fechaInicio.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace('-','/'); }
        set { fechaInicio = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    }

    public String fechaTerminoStr {
        get { return fechaTermino.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace('-', '/'); }
        set { fechaTermino = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    }

}
```

When I load the View, the controller loads the data into the model and shows the data in the View, but when I submit the form to do the search, the model comes empty to the controller HttpPost enabled method.

I know that there may be some major optimizations that can be done on my code, but right now I need to find out why the MVC Helper doesn't return the model when I submit the form.

Note: I have posted the code from another custom strongly typed html helper that it's not used in my view, but the helpers that are used in the view were coded in the same way.

EDIT: As requested, I'm posting the code for:
Combo:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Combo(this HtmlHelper html, string id, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, string alto = "", string ancho = "",
          Boolean activo = true, Boolean visible = true, string tooltip = "", EjeZ ejeZ = EjeZ.Normal, Boolean multicolumna = false) {
         TagBuilder select = new TagBuilder("select");
         select.MergeAttribute("id", id);
         select.MergeAttribute("name", id);
         string estilos = string.Empty;
         if(alto.Length > 0) { estilos += "height:" + alto + ";"; }
         if(ancho.Length > 0) { estilos += "width:" + ancho + ";"; }
         if(!activo)
            select.MergeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
         if(!visible) {
            select.MergeAttribute("class", "Combo Oculto");
         } else {
            select.MergeAttribute("class", "Combo");
         }
         //select.AddCssClass("ComboNew");
         if(multicolumna) {
            select.MergeAttribute("multicol", "true");
         } else {
            select.MergeAttribute("multicol", "false");
         }


         if(ejeZ == EjeZ.Frente) {
            estilos += "z-index:" + maxEjeZ + ";";
         } else if(ejeZ == EjeZ.Atras) {
            estilos += "z-index:" + minEjeZ + ";";
         }

         select.MergeAttribute("style", estilos);

         TagBuilder option;
         foreach(SelectListItem item in items) {
            option = new TagBuilder("option");
            option.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value);
            option.MergeAttribute("label", item.Text);
            option.InnerHtml += item.Text;


            select.InnerHtml += option.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
         }
         select.MergeAttribute("title", tooltip);

         return MvcHtmlString.Create(select.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
      }
```

Numero:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Numero(this HtmlHelper html, string id, string alto = "", string ancho = "", Boolean activo = true,
          Boolean visible = true, int maxlength = 0, string valMax = "", string valMin = "", Boolean spinner = false,
          Int32 step = 1, Int32 decimales = 10, string tooltip = "", EjeZ ejeZ = EjeZ.Normal, string Numero = "") {
         var numero = new TagBuilder("input");

         numero.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
         numero.MergeAttribute("id", id);
         numero.MergeAttribute("name", id);
         numero.MergeAttribute("spinner", spinner.ToString( ));
         numero.MergeAttribute("step", step.ToString( ));
         numero.MergeAttribute("title", tooltip);
         numero.MergeAttribute("value", Numero);

         if(maxlength > 0)
            numero.MergeAttribute("maxlength", maxlength.ToString( ));

         numero.MergeAttribute("maximo", valMax);
         numero.MergeAttribute("minimo", valMin);
         numero.MergeAttribute("decimales", decimales.ToString( ));

         string estilos = string.Empty;
         if(alto.Length > 0) { estilos += "height:" + alto + ";"; }
         if(ancho.Length > 0) { estilos += "width:" + ancho + ";"; }
         if(!activo)
            numero.MergeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
         if(!visible) {
            numero.MergeAttribute("class", "Numero Oculto");
         } else {
            numero.MergeAttribute("class", "Numero");
         }

         if(ejeZ == EjeZ.Frente) {
            estilos += "z-index:" + maxEjeZ + ";";
         } else if(ejeZ == EjeZ.Atras) {
            estilos += "z-index:" + minEjeZ + ";";
         }

         numero.MergeAttribute("style", estilos);

         return MvcHtmlString.Create(numero.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));

      }
```

NumeroFor:

```
public static MvcHtmlString NumeroFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> numero, string id, string alto = "",
          string ancho = "", Boolean activo = true, Boolean visible = true, int maxlength = 0, string valMax = "", string valMin = "", Boolean spinner = false,
          Int32 step = 1, Int32 decimales = 10, string tooltip = "", EjeZ ejeZ = EjeZ.Normal) {

         var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(numero);
         var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(numero, html.ViewData);

         string valor = (metadata.Model == null) ? "" : metadata.Model.ToString( );

         return Numero(html, id, alto, ancho, activo, visible, maxlength, valMax, valMin, spinner, step, decimales, tooltip, ejeZ, valor);
      }
```

Calendario:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Calendario(this HtmlHelper html, string id, string fecha = "", string fechaFinal = "",
          string fechaInicial = "", string alto = "", string ancho = "", Boolean activo = true,
          Boolean visible = true, Boolean deshabilitaFeriados = false, string tooltip = "", EjeZ ejeZ = EjeZ.Normal) {
         var calendario = new TagBuilder("input");
         calendario.MergeAttribute("type", "Text");
         calendario.MergeAttribute("id", id);
         calendario.MergeAttribute("name", id);
         calendario.MergeAttribute("datepicker", id);
         calendario.MergeAttribute("fecha", fecha);
         calendario.MergeAttribute("fechafinal", fechaFinal);
         calendario.MergeAttribute("fechainicial", fechaInicial);
         calendario.MergeAttribute("deshabilitaferiados", deshabilitaFeriados.ToString( ));

         string estilos = string.Empty;
         if(alto.Length > 0) { estilos += "height:" + alto + ";"; }
         if(ancho.Length > 0) { estilos += "width:" + ancho + ";"; }
         if(!activo)
            calendario.MergeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
         if(!visible) {
            calendario.MergeAttribute("class", "Calendario Oculto");
         } else {
            calendario.MergeAttribute("class", "Calendario");
         }

         if(ejeZ == EjeZ.Frente) {
            estilos += "z-index:" + maxEjeZ + ";";
         } else if(ejeZ == EjeZ.Atras) {
            estilos += "z-index:" + minEjeZ + ";";
         }

         calendario.MergeAttribute("style", estilos);
         calendario.MergeAttribute("title", tooltip);

         return MvcHtmlString.Create(calendario.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
      }
```

CalendarioFor:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CalendarioFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> calendario,
          string id, string fechaFinal = "", string fechaInicial = "", string alto = "", string ancho = "", Boolean activo = true,
          Boolean visible = true, Boolean deshabilitaFeriados = false, string tooltip = "", EjeZ ejeZ = EjeZ.Normal) {

         var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(calendario);
         var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(calendario, html.ViewData);

         string valor = (metadata.Model == null) ? "" : metadata.Model.ToString( );

         return Calendario(html, id, valor, fechaFinal, fechaInicial, alto, ancho, activo, visible, deshabilitaFeriados, tooltip, ejeZ);
      }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the Combo, Number, Calendar, etc helper? the Label helper is not going to do anything to send data during a POST.

Comment: Maybe It's because the Controls ID are not matching the models properties?
I mean, in my helpers, you can assign an ID that doesn't have to match with the model's property name. 
I will try this tomorrow.
Source: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/11/26/why-all-the-lambdas.aspx